# C# WinForms / How to access the controls of the form containing a custom control?

Tags: .net, winforms

Let's say I got a CustomListView control added into MainForm.

```
// CustomListView.cs

class CustomListView : ListView
{
    public CustomListView()
    {
        ItemActivate += new EventHandler(ItemActivateEvent);
    }

    private void ItemActivateEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // update label in the parent form
    }
}
```

How can I access MainForm's other controls from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to create the EventHandler from within the MainForm. That way you can very easily control your CustomListView Control and also your MainForm Control from with your MainForm.

Something like this:

MAINFORM.CS:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Creates and displays the custom control on your MainForm and 
    //     attaches an event to it.

    CustomListViewControl lv = new CustomListViewControl();
    this.Controls.Add(lv);

    lv.ItemActivate += new EventHandler(ItemActivateEvent);
}

void ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some stuff with MainForm or its child controls in here.

    this.Text = "I am uber awesome";
    this.Hide();



}
```

Comment: You may need to set the Access Modifier to Public or Internal so the Form can access the CustomListView. I don't remember, you may not need to.

Comment: But wouldn't it be a preferable design if CustomListView managed its own events?